# Как задать тип переменной в js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, типы

Можно как-то задать тип переменной в js как в следующем коде на python?

```py
from clients import OneClient
from clients import TwoClient

abc: str = "abc"
client: TwoClient = OneClient(abc=abc)
```

Comment: Нельзя, в javascript нет аннотаций типов. Используйте typescript, в нём есть

Comment: или jsdoc______

Comment: или https://flow.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Довольно просто, переменные JavaScript не имеют типов. Типы есть у значений.

Язык позволяет нам писать код, подобный этому:

```
var foo = 42;
foo = 'the answer';
foo = function () {};
```

Поэтому указывать тип в объявлении переменной бессмысленно, так как тип диктуется значением переменной. Это довольно часто встречается в "динамических" языках, но если вам все же необходимо явно указывать типы, то стоит присмотреться к TypeScript.