# Явное привидение типов в JS

Tags: javascript, python, postgresql

Я недавно начал изучать JS. До этого учил python.
В python были такие строчки `name_var: int` или `name_var: str`. Эти строки говорят нам, что `name_var` имеет тип данных `int` или `str` соответственно. Или же в PostgreSQL `name_var::int` или `name_var::text`. **А что же с JS?** Как мне указать что я ожидаю в функции именно строковое значение. Или как я буду сравнивнивать переменные как я делал это в python благодаря функции `isinstance()`.

Comment: никак.  в любую функцию можно передать любую переменную

Comment: В Питоне это тоже ни разу не тип. Запись `name_var: int` для Питона значит не больше чем если бы это было написано в комментарии. Никто не запрещает написать, к примеру так: `name_var: int = "Text"`.

Comment: @grand разве name_var в `name_var: int` не используется как алиас?

Comment: Как алиас чего? `name_var` - это имя переменной. Переменная в Питоне может содержать чего угодно. То что стоит после двоеточия - это аннотация, которая ни к чему не обязывает. Её используют сторонние статические анализаторы для проверок кода и могут использовать редакторы для вывода подсказок. Также аннотации доступны во время исполнения кода, но как они будут (и будут ли) использованы решает разработчик. Сам Питон никак их не использует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самом JavaScript нету такого понятия как строгая типизация, проверить тип можно через `typeof(variable) === "string"` для простых переменных или `objectVar istanceof Array` для объектов.

```js
function MyClass(name) {
  if (!(this instanceof MyClass)) throw new Error("Sorry not an class");
  if (typeof(name) !== "string") throw new Error("First param must be string");
  this.name = name;
}

MyClass.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
}
```

Так-же есть некая надстройка над JS, используется очень часто в крупных проектах и активно поддерживается JavaScript сообществом - TypeScript https://www.typescriptlang.org/ .

```
function Hello(name: string): number {
    console.log("Hello ", name);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

В JS никак, welcome to динамическая типизация. В TypeScript можно. 
Здесь уже спрашивали:
[Как задать тип переменной в js?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1293986/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-js)